# How is the relation of expectations and order statistics of X and Y, if Y is a mean-perserving spread of X

Tags: random-variable, expected-value, order-statistics

I am searching now for quite some time for an answer with a source to the following question. $X$ and $Y$ are two random variables. $Y$ is a mean preserving spread of $X$. Now, how is the relation of the expectations and order statistics of $X$ and $Y$.

For example:

- Is $E[X_{(1:n)}]$ always bigger than $E[Y_{(1:n)}]$ (maybe also under some assumptions)?
  ($E[X_{(1:n)}]$ means: the expected value of the first order statistic of $X$ for $n$ independent draws of $X$)
- Are the expected values of the order statistics of $Y$ more widely spread than those of $X$?
- Are there other statements that apply to some or all of the order statistics?

I find it really difficult to precisely find the answer to this question, especially with a good source. Maybe someone remembers a paper or textbook where this question was answered?

This would be really helpful! Thank you in advance!